# Use Linq to Parse out XML Sibling Node - C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have a while loop that reads in a flat file one line at a time and parses out information and then adds it to an XML file.
Some of the information has to be transformed by calling a web service and I am having trouble pulling out the required values from the response XML.

Here is the XML I need to grab values out of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <Tags>
        <WTs>
            <WT>
                <ID>ID_1</ID>
                <Value>Value 1</Value>
            </WT>
            <WT>
                <ID>ID_2</ID>
                <Value>Value 2</Value>
            </WT>
            <WT>
                <ID>ID_3</ID>
                <Value>Value 3</Value>
            </WT>
        </WTs>
    </Tags>
</Root>
```

I tried using both Linq and xpath to grab the values.
What I need is to check the `ID` of each `WT` element and if it is the one I want, then grab the `Value` element.

Here is the C# code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(retValue);
string val1 = xdoc.Root.Elements("WTs")
      .Where(q => (string)q.Element("ID") == "ID_1")
      .Select(q => (string)q.Element("Value"))
      .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nVal 1 = {0}\n\n\n", val1);

val1 = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//WTs/WT[ID='ID_1']/Value");
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nVal1 = {0}\n\n\n", val1);
```

When I debug, the val1 variable is set to null. I think the problem might be with the Tags node being a child of the Root element and a parent to all the other nodes. I tried using something like `xdoc.Root.FirstNode` but this only allows me to choose `elementsafterself` and `elementsbeforeself`. I don't know how to access the children elements.

How can I grab the Value node based on the ID node's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `Tags` and `WT` elements in your query:

```
string val1 = xdoc.Root.Element("Tags").Element("WTs").Elements("WT")
                  .Where(q => (string)q.Element("ID") == "ID_1")
                  .Select(q => (string)q.Element("Value"))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or simply look for descendatns

```
string val1 = xdoc.Root.Descendants("WT")
                  .Where(wt => (string)wt.Element("ID") == "ID_1")
                  .Select(wt => (string)wt.Element("Value"))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

XPath solution will look like

```
string val1 = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//WT[ID='ID_1']/Value");
```

Comment: I tried both all three solutions and I am still getting null values. How can I test if the xdoc is correct? I am looking at it in the debugger watch, and the XML looks fine. Is there anything more I can do to check if the xdoc is correct?

Comment: @RXC make sure your real xml have exactly same structure as you posted, and that it does not have namespaces declared. Just verified solutions - all return `Value 1` for your sample xml. Note - you can use `Console.WriteLine(xdoc)` to verify content loaded in document

Comment: That is where my problem is. The XML has namespaces defined in the `Root` and `Tags` nodes. Is there any easy way to remove them or add them to the queries?

Comment: @RXC with linq query you can get default namespace of root `var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();` and then use it to provide full names of elements. E.g. `Descendants(ns + "WT")`. With xpath query usage of namespaces will be not that simple

Answer (score 1):

XPath would be my approach:

```
/Root/Tags/WTs/WT[ID = TargetValue]/Value
```

should do it, I realise that is very similar to what you show. I would start by double checking `xdoc` is what you think it is.